# Scheduling event based on an index date

Tags: calendar

Our data load occurs on the 3rd Monday of the month. I want to schedule related pre and post activities (e.g., 5 days prior or 2 days after). Can I schedule using an index date (i.e., 3rd Monday, in this case) such as 3rd Monday - 5 days? Using the weekly designation works for some months but you have to manually fix it for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula for finding the 3rd Monday of the month (based on your task "Start Date" - or substitute some similar date column name):

```
 =DATE(YEAR([Start Date]),MONTH([Start Date]),(3*7)+1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Start Date]),MONTH([Start Date]),8-2))
```

Note that the "3" in `(3*7)+1` denotes "3rd" and "Monday" is represented as "2" (as it's the second day of the week) in this part `8-2`.

From there, you can create other calculated columns and use the value derived in the calculated column above to determine the dates 5 days prior and 2 days after etc.

If you need more help, let me know.